# Driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am starting to develop with springboot and I have been stuck for 2 days. When i launch my app i get this line.

> 2020-07-08 11:54:46.377  WARN 33224 --- [         task-1]
> o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain
> connection to query metadata : Driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver claims
> to not accept jdbcUrl, jbdc:mysql://localhost:3306/decormoi

I understand, there is a problem with my url which refers to my database, but which one?

PLEASE  someone to help me?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have a typo in the URL

```
jbdc:mysql://localhost:3306/decormoi
```

should be

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/decormoi
```

Comment: i wasted 4 hours on this typo ! :(

Comment: For users who are trying to find difference `jbdc != jdbc`